# Log url to Spring controller from inside it

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

Suppose you have a *Spring MVC* controller, something like this

```
@Controller
public class RestController {
 
    @GetMapping(value = "/test")
    public @ResponseBody Test getTestData(...) {

        // console log path to controller: http://localhost:80/app/test
        return testData;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to *log/print* from inside the controller the url to it? In the example above the output would be something like `https://localhost:80/app/test`

Using  `.getRequestUrl` from the *servlet* is not behaving correctly.

Comment: "*Using `.getRequestUrl` from the servlet is not behaving correctly.*" - What is the actual and expected output?

Comment: Not sure, what you are trying to achieve, you can fetch the server ip from the request, you should know the application / context name, and you know the api invoked, why cant you create the required url

Comment: You can pass constants as annotation values. You can construct the URL based on several constants like (domain + restBasePath + instancePath(subPath))... Spring could not decide your absolute path, and you should know better than it the relative path.

Comment: @Turing85 with `.getRequestUrl` I get the link to the jsp something like `http://localhost:80/WEB-INF/view/.../test.jsp` Which isn't what I want. I want the link to the controller.

Comment: Your controller does not have any path set at the sample code... The getMapping itself has a mapping...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject UriComponentsBuilder as parameter then use the method toUriString(). From the documentation, it is used to build a relative URI from the current request’s, this should work as your are expected [Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-arguments).

```
@Controller
public class RestController {
...
    @GetMapping(value = "/test")
    public @ResponseBody Test getTestData(UriComponentsBuilder ucb, ...) {
        LOGGER.debug(ucb.toUriString());
        // console log path to controller: http://localhost:80/app/test
        return testData;
    }
...
}
```